# IIS flask is not able to run admin privilege commands

Tags: python, flask, iis

I am stuck in this setup for almost a week now. Hope that someone can guide me through it.

**Setup**

1. I have setup an IIS Server running Flask python code. (Using wfastcgi.py )
2. I have configured the Application Pool Identity to my own account. (Admin Permission)
3. I have changed all the files permission that are needed for this web deployment to "Everyone" - Full Control(Read,Write,Execute). (I understand the security risks, this is my staging environment.)
4. Web server is running fine and i have checked using the bottom code to know my python permission is administrator.

   ```
    def am_i_admin():
        try:
            is_admin = os.getuid() == 0
        except AttributeError:
            is_admin = ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0
        if is_admin == True:
            return "ADMIN"
        else:
            return "USER"
   ```

**Problem Statement**

1. I am trying to run administrator priv code on my flask IIS server which allow user within the same network to execute; such as

   ```
    subprocess.run(['ipconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    pyautogui.screenshot() #which take a screenshot of the web server and send over to the client.
   ```
2. I ran on my local jupyter notebook, and the above functions worked perfectly well.
3. But it failed to run on the IIS flask server.
4. I have also tried to setup pyautogui on flask server (stand alone without IIS), it worked.
5. What is the issue with the IIS server ?? Or are there more things that i need to configure. Are there security features that I can disable ?

**Subprocess error message:**

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\my_app.py", line 58, in <module>
    out = os.popen("ipconfig").read()
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 990, in popen
    bufsize=buffering)
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1090, in _get_handles
    errwrite = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_ERROR_HANDLE)
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

**pyautogui error:**

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\my_app.py", line 45, in <module>
    pyautogui.screenshot()
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 135, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 427, in _screenshot_win32
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
  File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 44, in grab
    include_layered_windows, all_screens
OSError: screen grab failed


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Answer (score 0):

> File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 44, in grab
> include_layered_windows, all_screens
> OSError: screen grab failed

To resolve the issue set stderr and stdin to subprocess.PIPE:

```
['where', 'wkhtmltopdf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
```

Reference: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/714

> File "c:\users\aspnet\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 44, in grab
> include_layered_windows, all_screens
> OSError: screen grab failed

Use below code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

OR

```
from PIL import Image
```